# Ajax script not working- Returns status 0 and readystate 0 and statustext empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using below code from w3schools on our website, and I get status=0 and readystate 0 and statustext as an empty value. Please let me know what I need to do to make it run.

Code:

```
     function delete_image(val)
    {
      var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  

      if(status==true)
      {


        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();


        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log(xhttp.status);
          if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.status);
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
          }
        };

        xhttp.open("GET", "/~vinayemmadi/delete_image.php", true);
        xhttp.send();   

      }
     }
```

Comment: `confirm` won't work in ajax function as it returns value true/false. So instead return its value and then check it

Comment: Where are you getting `status = 0` and `readystate = 0`?

Comment: @Ms.Nehal What are you talking about? He's not calling `confirm` in the AJAX code, he's calling it before making the AJAX call.

Comment: @Vinay Emmaadii, try `alert(status)`, just after the initialisation(i.e. 2nd line of the function) and check what do you get ? And instead I would suggest to change the variable name from status to something else ex. sta

Comment: @barmar I was printing them to console using console.log()

Comment: @Ms.Nehal since the other status is the key inside xhttp object I dont think it should have any affect on having same name.

Comment: When and where did you do that? The status won't change until you get into the `onreadystatechange` function. And it goes through several different stages while the AJAX request is in progress.

Comment: @barmar Oh, I will change it and try running it again. Thanks for that.

Comment: @barmar Yes,it worked when I put the code inside readystate. Thanks a lot for your help